# How do i recive post Values MVC3 (Jquery Ajax)

Tags: jquery, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Im new to MVC and this kind of programming, i guess this is quite trivial but after 5 hours of searching and trying i feel defeted. I have a post in my View that looks like this;

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Moo")',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "string",
        contentType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"}),
        success: function (data) {}
        });
    });
```

I then have a function in a controller that looks like this;

```
Function Moo(test As String) As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

When i run it the debugger shows that i get to the Return-statement, but i dont get any test to be assign any value (foo:bar).

Another consideration i have is that when i manage to recive the data from the ajax function, can i convert it back to a JSON or do i have to make my own class in a model and assign the varibles to that class?

Any input would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter/property names should match.

So if you expect a value with the name `test` in your action you need to send the value with the key `test`. So change `foo` to `test`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Moo")',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "string",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"test": "bar"}),
        success: function (data) {}
        });
    });
```

Note the correct contentType of JSON is `application/json`

If you have more complex data like `JSON.stringify({"test": "bar", "test1":"bar1"}),`
You can create an object on the server side (sorry for the C#)

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string test { get; set; }

    public string test1 { get; set; }
}
```

then you can use this model in your action:

```
Function Moo(test As MyClass) As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

And the MVC model binder will take of the parsing the data and filling in the properties. You can start learning about the model binding here: [The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much, im like a child on chrismas eve right now. :)

Comment: What would you say is the best way if my data-content is really big, can i convert the JSON back to a object on the server or do i make a model and assign the values?

Comment: You can send in basically any complex model. And if you create a model object on the server side the MVC model binding will take care of it:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: Then it was as a thought, so i cant just take in a JSON anyhow? Once again, thanks for the answers, it really made my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

this in another approach you may wan to try
[although it may not be the best]

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Moo")?test="testdata"',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "string",
        contentType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"test": "bar"}),
        success: function (data) {}
        });
    });
```

**the parameter name you pass should match the parameter name of the action method on server.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Moo")',
    type: "post",
    dataType: "text", //<---------------------this
    contentType: "application/json", // <-----this 
    data: JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"}),
    success: function (data) {}
    });
});
```

or you can try changing this too:

```
data: {foo : "bar"},
```

dataTypes are :

- `"xml"`: Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.
- `"html"`: Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
- `"script"`: Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.
- `"json"`: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.
- `"jsonp"`: Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback.
- `"text"`: A plain text string.